# Golang exec.Command Process

Tags: go, exec

The goal is to run
`bun create vite <project-name>`
via Golang's exec library.

The problem is that `bun create vite <project-name>` prompts you to "Select a framework"
[image]

How would I go about navigating this menu via the Golang program and choosing "Lit"?

Firstly, I do:

`cmd = exec.Command("bun", "create", "vite", "lit-element")`

But what comes next?

Comment: you might be able to pass arguments into the command to specify a framework.  That would be by far the simplest way

Answer (score 0):

On my machine I was able to use arrow keys to select `Lit` with the following code snippet (after also ensuring that `"os"` package is also imported):

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "bun create vite lit-element")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
err := cmd.Run()
```

Comment: sweet! and how do I programmatically input the arrow keys and send them into the process?